# What is the difference between widget_init and wp_widget_init hooks? Which one is better to use?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I was using widget and found that it has hook widget_init.
Like below and works well.

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("example_widget");'));
```

But the hook is "wp_widgets_init", so what's the difference here? Which is better?

Comment: just a note on *create_function()* - **`If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should be used instead.`** ...because it uses eval() => security issues + bad performance&memory usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of [wp_widgets_init](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L1151) it looks like the wp_widgets_init initializes internal widgets first and then calls generic widgets_init. As such you'll want to use the second one as you can relay on WP environment to be already setup.